# M-x set-variable does not work in Emacs 24.5.1

Tags: emacs

I recently upgraded Emacs 24.5.1 from 24.1 on my OSX machine. I use the native Cocoa Emacs application.

Since the upgrade, I have been unable to use `M-x set-variable` to change the value of a variable. The variable is defined in my `.emacs` with the syntax:

```
(defvar project-root-directory nil)
```

With the above definition, after Emacs starts up and the `.emacs` file is loaded without errors, when I hit `M-x set-variable`, Emacs complains that `project-root-directory` variable does not exist.

Did anything change with defvar syntax in Emacs 24.5 that disallows setting a variable using M-x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is **yes**, something did change for Emacs 24.5 that broke this feature.  More precisely, the breakage was introduced in Emacs 24.3, not 24.5.

Prior to Emacs 24.3 (that is, for decades!), it was enough to just put `*` as the first character of the doc string, to make a variable into a user variable, so it could be used with `set-variable`.  (The `*` does not show as part of the displayed doc string.)

In other words, prior to Emacs 24.3, all you needed to do was this, to be able to use `M-x set-variable`:

```
(defvar foo 42 "*This is a user variable.")
```

Was it a good idea for Emacs to drop this feature? Some think so. (I don't.)

---

What is the current situation?

As @Thomas said, `set-variable` works for variables that are defined using `defcustom`. More precisely, however, it is defined for variables for which `custom-variable-p` returns non-nil.

So you can still use `M-x set-variable` with a variable that was defined using `defvar`, provided you give it a non-nil `standard-value` property (this makes it satisfy `custom-variable-p`):

```
    (defvar foo 42 "This is a user variable.")
    (put 'foo 'standard-value 42)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail. It answers my nagging question about whether something was broken between 24.1 and 24.5 versions.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable should be a *user option* variable name, i.e., a Lisp variable
meant to be customized by users. Thus, use `defcustom` instead of `defvar`:

```lisp
(defcustom project-root-directory nil
  "The root directory of the project.")
```

You might want to come up with a better documentation string for the variable than the one in this example.

(This was already the case prior to Emacs24.)

Comment: Great, that worked well for me. Thanks. (Its strange that variables defined with 'defvar' used to define a user option variable name in my configuration earlier, but anyway, I will use defcustom in future)

Comment: Thanks, but could you please accept @Drew's answer as correct? I think it's much better than mine.

Comment: I had thought about it, but I didn't want to take away the points I awarded to you out of respect for being the first. Since it is your wish, and since Drew's answer is more detailed, I will accept his reply as the correct answer. :-)

Comment: Being first is one thing, but giving a more informative answer another ;-) Cheers!